# How can I get ob_start() to work in a class within my Wordpress Plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to add ob_start into a class within my Wordpress plugin as below:

```
class ObStart {
  public static function callback($buffer){
    return $buffer;
  }

  public static function add_ob_start(){
    ob_start("callback");
  }

  public static function flush_ob_end(){
    ob_end_flush();
  }
}

add_action('init', array( 'ObStart', 'add_ob_start' ) );
add_action('wp_footer', array( 'ObStart', 'flush_ob_end' ) );
```

This doesn't seem to work and instead results in this error:

```
Warning:  ob_start(): function 'callback' not found or invalid function name in <b>\wp-content\plugins\timeline-plugin\obstart.php on line 8

Notice:  ob_start(): failed to create buffer in \wp-content\plugins\timeline-plugin\obstart.php on line 8

Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at \wp-includes\formatting.php:5520) in \wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1251

Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at \wp-includes\formatting.php:5520) in \wp-includes\pluggable.php</b> on line 1254
```

Is it possible to get the ob_start to work in a class? If yes, where am I going wrong?

Comment: There is a comment to the [ob_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) suggesting you can use an array, but that's calling it from the outside. The obvious solution here would be: `ob_start(["this", "callback"])` but I am totally unsure if that would work, the comment is 15 years old!

Comment: When I use an array it gives the error:
(Warning:  ob_start(): class 'this' not found in ...)

Comment: Well, it was worth a try, wasn't it? I was afraid that that would happen.

Comment: Figured out the solution:

Comment: `
class Obstart {

  public static function callback($buffer){
    return $buffer;
  }

  public static function add_ob_start(){
  global $buffer;
    ob_start(self::callback($buffer));
  }

  public static function flush_ob_end(){
    ob_end_flush();
  }
}

add_action('init', array( 'Obstart', 'add_ob_start' ) );
add_action('wp_footer', array( 'Obstart', 'flush_ob_end' ) );
`

Comment: Long pieces of code in a comment are difficult to read. If you found the solution then it is perfectly fine to answer your own question. You might even get upvotes for that! I see you statically call the `callback` method with `self::callback($buffer)`. Any reason to do that, and not choose the normal `$this->callback($buffer)`? See: [self vs. this in PHP](https://www.diffen.com/difference/self-vs-this-PHP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Obstart 
{ 
      public static function callback($buffer)
      { 
           return $buffer; 
      } 

      public static function add_ob_start()
      { 
           global $buffer; 

           ob_start( self::callback($buffer) ); 
      }

      public static function flush_ob_end()
      { 
           ob_end_flush(); 
      } 
} 

add_action('init', array( 'Obstart', 'add_ob_start' ) ); 
add_action('wp_footer', array( 'Obstart', 'flush_ob_end' ) );
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.